# if the file not exits then return no error vb

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have start this application every things its work fine but i have a small bug but i can not find the solution to solve the error.

i have debug it and the error its because the file not exist
is there any way to me to populate my datagridview with all *.gif images From a directory and the check if its null or some thing like that.
What i mean is is there any way to my to populate all gif images found on the chose Directory?
in fact i have all ready try like this but i get one error "Provided column already belongs to the DataGridView control.

```
Well finaly i have found a solution to load all images from a directory to a datagridview programmatic
```

Here Is The Working Code

```
Public Class Form5

Private Sub addBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addBtn.Click
    'Populate()
    ShowImages()

End Sub
'CLEAR DATAGRIDVIEW
Private Sub clearBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearBtn.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
End Sub
'WHEN AN IMAGE IS CLICKED
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    MessageBox.Show("You Clicked Image At Col: " + e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + " Row: " + e.RowIndex.ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Public Sub ShowImages()

    Dim directory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\avitogifconverter\")

    If directory.Exists Then

        Dim pngFiles() As System.IO.FileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*.gif")

        For Each pngFile As System.IO.FileInfo In pngFiles

            If pngFile.Exists Then

                Dim image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pngFile.FullName)

                Using image
                    Dim count = 1
                    ' do something with the image like show in picture box
                    'CONSTRUCT IMG COLUMN
                    Dim imgCol As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
                    imgCol.HeaderText = "Photo"
                    imgCol.Name = "Col 1"
                    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgCol)
                    'CONSTRUCT ROWS
                    'FIRST ROW

                    Dim img As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pngFile.FullName)

                    Dim row As Object() = New Object() {img, img, img}


                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
                End Using

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `File.Exists(theName)` ?  not sure what you are asking because if you are populating from the list of files in a directory, they must exist.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix Hi Tank you for replay.what i mean is i populate the image in the gridview by a specific Directory file like Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\avitogifconverter\out (2).gif")
    Dim img1 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\avitogifconverter\out (3).gif")
    Dim img2 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\avitogifconverter\out (4).gif")

Comment: @Plutonix I what i mean is is there the way to do this with out specific the image file one by one on a kind of a loop populate all existing image files there

Comment: That seems like a very different question than that posed in the actual post.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It sounds like [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Mark Tank you for the help can you give me a litle example how can i do pls.

Comment: @Mark for ex. lie this Public Shared Sub Main()
        ' Make a reference to a directory.
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("c:\")
        ' Get a reference to each file in that directory.
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        ' Display the names of the files.
        Dim fri As FileInfo
        For Each fri In fiArr
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        'SECOND ROW

        img = Image.FromFile(di)
        img1 = Image.FromFile(di)
        img2 = Image.FromFile(di)
        row = New Object() {img, img1, img2}
        Next fri
    End Sub 'Main

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx), you could do something like this:

```
Dim row = New List(Of Image)(3)
For Each filename In Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\avitogifconverter", "*.gif")
    row.Add(Image.FromFile(filename))
    If row.Count = 3 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray())
        row.Clear()
    End If
Next
If row.Count > 0 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray())
    row.Clear()
End If
```

Comment: i have try like this but i get this error 
  Message=No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean newRow, Object[] values)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
       at youtubetojpg.Form5.addBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Monchique Discovery\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\youtubetojpg\youtubetojpg\Form5.vb:line 14

Comment: Of course! How many columns do you want in your gridview? You must create a data table and define that first, then add rows to the data table then set the datagridview data source oto datatable